# check file - line by line to match criteria

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with some user listed. ie: `alluser.list` as following:

```
 user1
 user4
 user2
 user4
 user5
 user3
 user2
```

and I have another one,  named `userbanned.list` like:

```
 user5
 user4
 user2
```

Now I am looking a simple way to process the `alluser.list` file and compare with `userbanned.list`, if it match, then I would like to add a flag like True/False at the end of the line.

The result should be something like this :

```
 user1 FALSE
 user4 TRUE
 user2 TRUE
 user4 TRUE
 user5 TRUE
 user3 FALSE
 user2 TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`;

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ seen[$0]++;next } 
    { print $0 (($0 in seen)?" TRUE":" FALSE")}' userbanned.list alluser.list
user1 FALSE
user4 TRUE
user2 TRUE
user4 TRUE
user5 TRUE
user3 FALSE
user2 TRUE
```

`awk` break-down:

```
NR==FNR    - Execute next block for 1st file only "userbanned.list"

seen[$0]++ - Create an associative array with the key as '$0' (whole line) of
             file "userbanned.list"

next       - continue read next line of file "userbanned.list"

print $0   - Print the whole line of "alluser.list" file, , now FNR reset to 1 
             since next file read by awk, but NR is still incrementing until the last 
             line from last file read.

(($0 in seen)?" TRUE":" FALSE")
           - This known as Ternary operator '(condition)?"If-True":"If-False"'. It's
             short form of if/else/ and checks if current line in file "alluser.list" 
             exists in array then print "TRUE" else "FALSE".
```

I see also you have duplicated users which it will cause those print twice or more, you can uniqe the lines in both files then pass it to `awk` like below:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ seen[$0]++;next } { print $0 (($0 in seen)?" TRUE":" FALSE")}
    ' <(sort -u userbanned.list) <(sort -u alluser.list)
user1 FALSE
user2 TRUE
user3 FALSE
user4 TRUE
user5 TRUE
```